# How to cause Eclipse to copy a certain project folder into the respective bin directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a conf folder with log4j configuration in it:

```
PS Z:\dev\poc\Server> dir


    Répertoire : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::Z:\dev\poc\Server


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d----    06/12/2011    23:37        <DIR> .settings
d----    07/12/2011    12:24        <DIR> bin
d----    06/12/2011    13:43        <DIR> conf
d----    07/12/2011    12:09        <DIR> logs
d----    04/12/2011    15:42        <DIR> src
-a---    07/12/2011    13:32         4571 .classpath
-a---    06/12/2011    12:01          430 .project
-a---    06/12/2011    15:08        12458 hs_err_pid7504.log
-a---    06/12/2011    13:43         2510 Program.launch


PS Z:\dev\poc\Server>
```

What I want is that Eclipse copy that folder to be near the main class file, so if the `main` method is in the **src\com\shunra\poc\Program.java**, then after building the project the conf directory should find itself under **bin\com\shunra\poc**. This is like the **Copy On Build** msbuild rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `conf` an Eclipse Source Folder. Then all the contents of `conf` will be copied into `bin`.

Just click on `Add Folder`, browse to your `conf` folder and click ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new source folder and put the desired folder structure into it. All source folders will be copied to the bin directory by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are within your project, set the folder to be a source directory as suggested by the other posters.

If the files are elsewhere, there are a number of ways to do this, the easiest being to use an External Builder. Create a small .bat file containing the copy commands, and in your project Properties->Builders, do New..., choose Program and  and set the command to execute to be your script.